# Xcode warning when using MapKit and CoreLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, core-location

I'm attempting to use implement an instance of `MKMapView`, use `CoreLocation` to track the users location, and then zoom in to where they are.

I only want to track the user's location when I'm in the foreground. Since my app is targeted for iOS8, I have a plist entry for the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

When I run the app for the first time, the app appropriately asks if it can access my location. After I click 'Allow', I then receive the following warning from Xcode:

`Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.`

...which is a bit confusing, as I am in fact calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, as can be seen in my code below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation MapView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self locationManager];
    [self updateLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    self.locationManager = nil;
}

- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {
    //We only want to get the location when the app is in the foreground
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    if (!_locationManager) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    }
    return _locationManager;
}

- (void)updateLocation {
    _mapView.userTrackingMode = YES;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this warning would be occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, that is true. But are you waiting until you *get* authorization? No, you are not. You (as the user) are tapping Allow, but that's happening too late: your code has *already* continued,  going straight on to tell the map view to start tracking the user's location.

Just look at the docs on `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`:

> When the current authorization status is kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, this method runs asynchronously

Get that? *Runs asynchronously*. That means that asking for permission happens in the background on another thread.

And the docs go on to say:

> After the status is determined, the location manager delivers the results to the delegate’s `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` method

So, implement that method. If you have just obtained permission, *that* is the signal that you can start using the location manager.

Also, you are missing an important step: you are not *checking* what the status actually *is*. You should only be asking for authorization if *the status is undetermined*. If the status is restricted or denied, you must not use the location manager at all; and if the status is granted, there is no point asking for authorization again.

So, just to sum up, your logical flowchart should be:

- Check status.
- Is the status Restricted or Denied? Stop. You cannot use get location updates or do location on a map.
- Is the status Granted? Proceed to get location updates or do location on a map.
- Is the status Undetermined? Request authorization and stop. Treat `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` as the completion handler for your authorization request. At that point, go back to start of the flowchart!

Comment: Added more info. The logic here is quite complicated.

Comment: Added even more info, spelling out the logical flowchart for how to do this properly.