# CoreLocation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I've added the CoreLocation Library, along with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to info.plist but when I compile and run, it does not display the current location or prompt the user to allow access to current location. I currently have the following below, but it just displays the entire US. and

```
The authorization status of location services is changed to: Not determined
```

is printed to the log, but I'm not being prompted to allow access to current location nor am I receiving the alert. I tried following the logic and flowchart here: [Xcode warning when using MapKit and CoreLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495288/xcode-warning-when-using-mapkit-and-corelocation) but it didn't work.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var loadPoints:[Int: MapPointAnnotation] = [Int:MapPointAnnotation]()
var map:MKMapView?
var loads: [Load]?
var rightButton: UIButton?
var selectedLoad:Load?
var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


   // Core Location
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){

        print("The authorization status of location " +
            "services is changed to: ")

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .Denied:
            println("Denied")
        case .NotDetermined:
            println("Not determined")
        case .Restricted:
            println("Restricted")
        default:
            println("Authorized")
        }

}

func displayAlertWithTitle(title: String, message: String){
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Default,
        handler: nil))

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .Denied:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Not Determined",
                message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        case .NotDetermined:
            manager = CLLocationManager()
            if let locationManager = self.manager{
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        case .Restricted:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Restricted",
                message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        default:
            println("Default")
        }

    } else {

        println("Location services aren't enabled")
    }

}

convenience init(frame:CGRect){
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.view.frame = frame

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"selectAnnotation:", name: "selectAnnotation", object: nil)

    self.map = MKMapView(frame: frame)
    self.map!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.map!)
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1.0
    var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1.0

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    map!.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,make sure you have this key in plist
[image]

Second,request location service in `viewDidLoad`,I test with these code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var manager:CLLocationManager!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    if(NSString(string:UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue >= 8.0){
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        
        print("The authorization status of location " +
            "services is changed to: ")
        
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .Denied:
            println("Denied")
        case .NotDetermined:
            println("Not determined")
        case .Restricted:
            println("Restricted")
        default:
            println("Authorized")
        }
        
}
```

And get output
[image]

You have to run this on device and if you can not get alert,try uninstall the app,then run again

Comment: I tried the updated version but it didn't work, so I updated my code and took a snapshot of it.

Comment: Can you make a breakpoint in viewDidLoad to check if the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization ` is called?

Comment: It isn't being called.

Comment: Try delete `NSLocationAlwaysUseDescription`,you do not need add both in pist

Comment: It didn't make a difference.

Comment: I tried creating  a new project and running only your code but I get the same result.

Comment: Do you add plist of this key 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription'? in new project?

Comment: I did and there was still nothing