# NSLocation doesn't wait for me to click allow

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocation

When I run the code, the window pops asking for permission to use location but disappears almost immediately, not giving the user a chance to click "Allow". Is there a way to force this action before proceeding?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var map:MKMapView?
var manager:CLLocationManager!

convenience init(frame:CGRect){
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.view.frame = frame

    self.map = MKMapView(frame: frame)
    self.map!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.map!)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Core Location
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){

        print("The authorization status of location services is changed to: ")

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .Denied:
            println("Denied")
        case .NotDetermined:
            println("Not determined")
        case .Restricted:
            println("Restricted")
        default:
            println("Authorized")
        }

}

func displayAlertWithTitle(title: String, message: String){
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Default,
        handler: nil))

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .Denied:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Not Determined",
                message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        case .NotDetermined:
                manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .Restricted:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Restricted",
                message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        default:
            println("Default")
        }

    } else {
        println("Location services are not enabled")
    }

}


func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1.0
    var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1.0

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    map!.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode warning when using MapKit and CoreLocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495288/xcode-warning-when-using-mapkit-and-corelocation)

Comment: I tried doing exactly that and updated my question to include what I implemented but now it does't even prompt the user to enable location services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` before you get the result from the `manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. Even though you call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, you're updating the user's location before you ever get the result of that method (I had the exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495288/xcode-warning-when-using-mapkit-and-corelocation) as you, actually!)

The answer to that question explains the solution well. Basically, you'll need to implement the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` delegate method, which is called any time the authorization status changes based on user input. If the user did authorize tracking, then you can call `manager.startUpdatingLocation()`.

Also, for a Swift example of how to implement these methods, take look at this [guide](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/).

Comment: I tried doing exactly that and updated my question to include what I implemented but now it does't even prompt the user to enable location services.

Comment: @PabloPicasso, did you add the `NSLocationUsageDescription` string in your `Info.plist` file? (See "Knowing When to Start Location Services": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: I didn't. I want location services to be enabled, every time the app is launched.

Comment: @PabloPicasso The problem is, upon the first launch of an app by a user, location services shouldn't be enabled until it's given permission. That's besides the point though---what that string does is provide the user with a description of why you want to get their location.

Comment: I have NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription added to the p.list . before when I didn't include switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(), it prompted the user to allow location services, but now it doesn't do it at all

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class StartViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupLocationManager()

}

func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    locationHandler()
}

func locationHandler() {

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied) {
            // The user denied authorization

        } else if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
            // The user accepted authorization

        } else if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined){
            // The user not determiend authorization

        }else if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse){
            // In use

        }else{ }
    }else{
        //Access to user location permission denied!

    }


}



}//class
```

Be successful.